# Is there a way to count how many observations within specific values are in a variable?

Tags: r

I want to count how many observations in a variable lays within three groups defined by : (> x & < y)

I´ve tried two ways:

separately:

```
table(edit[ ,2]>110 & edit[ ,2]<323)
```

then

```
 table(edit[ ,2]>509 & edit[ ,2]<991)
```

and then

```
table(edit[ ,2]>4110 & edit[ ,2]<4391)
```

In one line:

```
table(edit[ ,2] >110& edit[ ,2] <323|edit[ ,2]>509 & edit[ ,2]<991|edit[ ,2]>1110&edit[ ,2]<4289)
```

When doing it separately it shows only FALSE values in the three groups, but when doing it in one line some TRUE values appear.

Comment: You one-line version contains `|edit[ ,2]>1110` which does not appear in your three-line version.

Comment: A reproducible example would make it much easier to answer and understand